# How do I exit private browsing mode in iOS but retain all of my private tabs?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, web-browsing

When I exit private mode in Safari, all of my tabs go away. How do I take all of my tabs with me out of private mode?

Comment: Copy all the URLs from the URL bar into an email or other document? Of course that doesn't preserve history, form fills, etc.

Comment: I've reopened this question at your request, but please note it was automatically closed by the system due to its status. For more info refer to [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). If you find that the question fails to get an answer you may need to place a [bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of iOS 12 beta 2 and below, **this is not currently possible with Safari.**

As said by @Snowbody,

> [You can copy & paste] all the URLs from the URL bar into an email or other document[.] Of
>   course that doesn't preserve history, form fills, etc.

Your best option is to either find a different browser with that feature (maybe create a new question) or to [submit a feature request to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).

Comment: Thats a record: **31 secs** for acceptance and upvote. Thanks! :)